# List Roles that sum of expenses are larger than average

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for asking this simple question(Maybe?). I am a newbie in SQL and I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem on my own.

I have three different tables but they share the same primary IDs.

L Table looks like this

```
L_Id  L_Nam
L1     GA
L2     FL
L3     NC
```

The R Table looks like this

```
R_Id  R_Name
R1     Same
R2     Steve
R3     Tony
R4     Roy
R5     Carol
R6     Jane
R7     Emma
```

The E Table looks like this

```
L_Id  R_Id      E_Date          E_Amt
L1     R1     2019-08-02         100
L1     R1     2019-08-05         400
L1     R1     2019-08-11         50
L2     R2     2019-08-02         150
L2     R2     2019-08-01         400
 :      :         :               :
L3     R6     2019-08-21         1020
L3     R7     2019-08-29         2000
```

There are two goals that I am trying to solve.

1. Calculate the sum of E_Amt from the E table base on the month from E_Date and L_Name from the L table then list the R_Name
2. Only list the R_Name that is greater or equal to the Average Monthly expense of any location they had expenses in that month.

I am still stuck on my first task.
Here is my approach

```
Select 
R.R_Id,R.R_Name,
SUM(E.E_Amt),
month(E.E_Date)
from L inner join E on
L.L_Id = E.L_Id
inner join R on
R.R_Id = E.R_Id
GROUP By E.R_Id, month(E.E_Date);
```

But my query isn't working so I am wondering what did I do wrong and what approach I need to take in order to solve the goals.

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237900/discussion-on-question-by-codingstark-list-roles-that-sum-of-expenses-are-larger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a query that gives you the sums per month and role. This is the base you build your query on that compares month's role sum with the month's average sum.

```
with my_base as
(
  select 
    r.role_id, r.role_name,
    sum(e.expense_amt) as sum_expense_amt,
    date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') as month
  from locations l
  inner join expenses e on e.location_id = l.location_id
  inner join roles r on r.role_id = e.role_id
  group by r.role_id, date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m')
)
select *
from my_base
where sum_expense_amt >=
(
  select avg(sum_expense_amt)
  from my_base all_roles
  where all_roles.month = my_base.month
);
```

Or make this two subqueries in the `WITH` clause. Here is an example with a join. (I don't like the join much, I prefer a subquery like above, because conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause in my opinion, not in the `FROM` clause. But why not show alternatives ;-)

```
with my_base as
(
  select 
    r.role_id, r.role_name,
    sum(e.expense_amt) as sum_expense_amt,
    date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') as month
  from locations l
  inner join expenses e on e.location_id = l.location_id
  inner join roles r on r.role_id = e.role_id
  group by r.role_id, date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m')
)
, averages as
(
  select month, avg(sum_expense_amt) as avg_sum_expense_amt
  from my_base
  group by month
)
select my_base.*
from my_base
join averages on averages.month = my_base.month
             and averages.avg_sum_expense_amt <= my_base.sum_expense_amt
;
```

Or use a window function. This is my preferred way of writing the query.

```
select role_id, role_name, sum_expense_amt, avg_sum_expense_amt, month
from
(
  select 
    r.role_id, r.role_name,
    sum(e.expense_amt) as sum_expense_amt,
    avg(sum(e.expense_amt)) over (partition by date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m'))
      as avg_sum_expense_amt,
    date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') as month
  from locations l
  inner join expenses e on e.location_id = l.location_id
  inner join roles r on r.role_id = e.role_id
  group by r.role_id, date_format(e.transaction_date, '%Y-%m')
) aggregated
where sum_expense_amt >= avg_sum_expense_amt;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4de13ea1946c6542e5ca4631d5d658c

All of these queries require at least MySQL 8, which should not be a problem because that version is aready three years old. In older versions neither CTEs (the `WITH` clause) nor analytic functions are featured. (In those old versions you'd have to write the base subquery twice.)

Comment: Got it. I am wondering if this applies to a larger amount of data. Which approach will be faster regarding the processing time.

Comment: I don't know. A perfect optimizer would come up with the same execution plan for all three queries. I don't know which query MySQL's optimizer handles best.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question,

> Calculate the sum of E_Amt from the E table base on the month from
> E_Date and L_Name from the L table then list the R_Name

Try:

```
select 
           r.Role_Name,
           a.month_of_date,
           sum(a.sum_expenses) as total_sum
    from (       
      select l.Location_Name,
             e.Location_Id,
             month(e.Transaction_Date) as month_of_date,
             e.Role_Id,
             sum(Expense_Amt)  as sum_expenses
    from Expenses e 
    inner join Locations l
    on e.Location_Id = l.Location_Id
    group by month_of_date,e.Location_Id,l.Location_Name,e.Role_Id 
      ) as a inner join Roles r on a.Role_Id=r.Role_Id
      group by r.Role_Name,a.month_of_date ;
```

or

```
select r.Role_Id,
       r.Role_Name,
       a.month_of_date,
       a.sum_expenses
from (       
  select l.Location_Name,
         e.Location_Id,
         month(e.Transaction_Date) as month_of_date,
         e.Role_Id,
         sum(Expense_Amt)  as sum_expenses
from Expenses e 
inner join Locations l
on e.Location_Id = l.Location_Id
group by month_of_date,e.Location_Id,l.Location_Name,e.Role_Id 
  ) as a inner join Roles r on a.Role_Id=r.Role_Id;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/3

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/2

As per second question, if I understood correctly, try:

> Only list the R_Name that is greater or equal to the Average Monthly
> expense of any location they had expenses in that month.

```
select r.Role_Name 
from Roles r
inner join 
(
  select 
       Role_Id,
       avg(Expense_Amt) as average_per_month,
       sum(Expense_Amt) as total_sum_per_month,
       Locations.Location_Id          
from Expenses 
inner join Locations  on Expenses.Location_Id=Locations.Location_Id
group by month(Transaction_Date),Role_Id,Locations.Location_Id
) as a on r.Role_Id=a.Role_Id
where average_per_month<=total_sum_per_month
group by r.Role_Name ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/7

Comment: It works perfectly fine! Thanks!
As for question 2, how should I add an argument/condtion

Comment: If I am looking for greater or equal to the Average Monthly expense of any location they had expenses in that month. I can change ```average_per_month>=total_sum_per_month to average_per_month<=total_sum_per_month``` ?

Comment: I am going to check it now!

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. But I am wondering am I understand the question correctly. Here is the question: "List all the Roles whose Total Monthly expense for a given month and location is greater or equal than the Average Monthly expense of any location they had expenses in that month. " So based on my understanding, I separate the question into two parts.

Comment: @Egest Basha, thats what I understand as well. Thanks so much!